# I can't click css element when I use selenium with ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

HTML code

```
<div id="M02" style="position: absolute; left: 10px; top: 19px; text-align: left; cursor: pointer; z-index: 6; width: 211px; color: black; 
background-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);" onmousemove="highlight(this);" onmouseout="restore(this);" onclick="NewPage( this );" class="ME">
<span class="EN" style="font-weight: normal;">PC setting</span></div>
```

I get issue in below steps, it says " NoMethodError: undefined method `element_present' ".
This is Ruby code from selenium IDE

```
  assert element_present(:css, "span")
    @driver.find_element(:css, "span").click
    @driver.find_element(:css, "#M02 > span.EN").click
```

element_present code

```
def element_present?(how, what)
    $receiver.find_element(how, what)
    true
  rescue Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError
    false
  end
```

Comment: I suppose it should be `assert element_present?(:css, "span")`. You missed question sign.

Comment: yes, it should be " assert element_present?(:css, "span"). " But it still can't run normally. Even I tried python it still fail. But it runs normally on selenium IDE.